# Building an incomplete binary tree

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm trying to build an incomplete binary tree from data provided in a text file

```
2
3 8
2 10 0 12
1 8 0 0 4 0
```

which would form a tree like this:

[image: Example tree]

I know roughly what I need to do, I think:

- read in from the file line-by-line.
- pass an array to the build function.
- As it's building the tree, the tree data type will keep track of the last nodes that it added in an array of pointers (eg, if we just finished adding the 3rd row of the text file, the a previous nodes array would look like pointers to the nodes containing `[2 10 12]`
- as we start adding the 4th line, we create an array of 3*2=6 length to store pointers to the nodes as we add them.
- we go through the array of pointers from the previous run (containing `[2 10 12]`) and create left and right children nodes for any non-zero keys that got passed through.  We put pointers to those nodes in our 6-long array.
- when we get a blank line, we're done.

The problem I'm running into is, I'm not sure how to store a array of pointers to nodes that changes size each time I call the build function and is a class variable (for the Tree class).  Am I going about this the right way?  Is there an easier way to approach this?

Comment: Is efficiency a concern? You certainly don't need your array of pointers unless you are trying to be efficient. You could just use the position of each integer within it's line to tell you where to add that integer.

Comment: Another way would be to build the tree from the leaves up (instead of the root down), that would require reading the whole file before starting to build the tree but it would be pretty simple.

Comment: No, I'm not worried about efficiency.  If the information in the text file described a complete tree (ie if row n had 2^n values), then I could just use the position to know where to put the value.  However, each row of the text file only has information if the previous row's node was non-null so it isn't all that easy to use position to tell where which should be the parent node.

Comment: I'm not seeing what the problem is when it's an incomplete tree. I'm assuming that only the last row would be incomplete (like your example), are you sure that's not the case?

Comment: But even if each row could be imcomplete, then you have to make an assumption that only the left most nodes will be created (otherwise the problem is ambiguous) so I still don't see the problem.

Comment: How would you go about tracking what nodes were created on the previous iteration when you go about adding nodes on the current iteration, though?  I guess efficiency is a bit of a concern because I'm trying to avoid wading through the tree to figure out where to put the next node when I could just keep track of what the previously created nodes were.

Comment: if I have a structure called Node, can I create a class array (in the Tree class) such as `Node *listOfNodes[];` for tracking the previously created nodes?

Comment: That would be `Node **listOfNodes;` and it would have to be dynamically allocated. It would be a lot easier to use `std::vector<Node*>` that would solve your size changing problem in a easy way. I'm not sure such a data structure belongs in your class however. Its only used when building the tree it isn't an inherent part of the tree.

Comment: What's the term for that data type (in order to read up on how to use it?)  Would I then access elements in it by calling `listOfNodes[i]`?

Comment: Is this a homework? You probably want to keep two `std::vector<Node*>`, one for the previous row and one for the current row you are building. Current griws as you add nodes to it. Once you finish a row, `previous=current; current.resize(0);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like 2D array, `array[row][column]`, you can use `2D vector` ie. `vector< vector<int> > V` is a vector of vectors.

In `vector< vector<int> > V`, inside vector indicate row, and outside vector indicate column `(for your understanding I just tell)`.

Here 2D vector is resize able. Not necessary that every column size will be equal. You can handle `push, pop` and you can store data according your memory size.

Example:

You can resize like of that:

```
int num_of_col = 5;
int num_of_row = 9;
double init_value = 3.14;

vector< vector<double> > matrix;
//now we have an empty 2D-matrix of size (0,0). Resizing it with one single command:
matrix.resize( num_of col , vector<double>( num_of_row , init_value ) );
// and we are good to go ...
```

You can learn here [vector](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/languages/C++/vectormemory.html)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use a std::vector instead of array? It behaves exactly like an array but is resizable.

Example of usage:

```
using namespace std;
Node *a = new Node;
vector<Node*> vec;
vec.push_back(a);
```

Comment: Because when a vector grows, it may move in memory, invalidating existing pointers.

Comment: How does the vector moving in memory invalidate existing pointers? Could you kindly explain that?

Comment: Because pointers between nodes in the vector will no longer point to the same nodes.

Comment: So you are basically saying that the values of the Node* objects being stored in the vector will change each time the vector changes its size? If so, then i highly disagree

Comment: You're right -- I didn't notice that you were holding pointers, rather than objects.

Comment: Actually, even if we were holding objects (vector<Node>), the data stored in the vector still wouldn't be affected at all when the vector gets expanded because the objects present in the vector before expansion would be duplicated for use after expansion

Comment: When the vector was expanded, the `Node*`s held by the `Node`s would no longer point into allocated memory.

Comment: Oh you mean the Node* pointers inside Node objects of the vector? Ya i agree they will get invalidated. I thought you were talking about objects directly owned by the vector. Nice observation :)